# Add 1 to variable inside of an echo expression

Tags: php, echo, increment

Getting very confused with echoing an HTML anchor with a variable inside.

```
<?php
echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="?p=" . $current_page +1" . ">Next</a>';
?>
```

I've tried so many variations of lost which ones I've tried. One of the attempts was with curly brackets `{` but still nothing. I know I'm getting my single and double quotes muddled up!

Could somebody please put me straight on this one. Also, what is the rules for apostrophes and quotes in PHP. If I want to echo something, what shall I start it with, an apostrophe or a quote.

Comment: @deceze do you make any distinction between "slip of the finger" typos and "teachable moment" typos in your philosophy on closing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php
echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="?p='.($current_page + 1).'">Next</a>';
?>
```

If you want to do some math of other trickery inside an echo, you will need to surround it in brackets.

Edit: @DaveRandom points out that the exception to the *trickery* clause is `$var++` and `++$var`.

Comment: `If you want to do some math of other trickery inside an echo, you will need to surround it in brackets.` - exception to this rule is `$var++` and `++$var`. Although actually there's also a trick to call a function without breaking out of the quotes using variable variables, but it's so horrible I'm not even going to post it for fear of someone using it.

Comment: This answer would benefit from an explanation as to what was changed from OP's code and why. Currently users are left to guess as to what the solution/cause of their problem is from this answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `'` when printing string, everything inside is treated as a text.

If you use `"`, variables passed inside are converted to the their values.

However it's impossible to do a math operations inside `"`. You have to escape it and do it in 'PHP way'.

```
<?php
echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="?p=' . ($current_page +1) .'">Next</a>';
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use double quotes `"something"` and surround the variables with curly brackets when they are inside the quotes.

```
echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='?p={$current_page+1}'>Next</a>";
```

You can also use string concatenation, which basically means joining a few strings together:

```
echo 'something' . 'something else' . $my_variable;
```

As for escaping, if anywhere inside some quotes you want to insert a quote of the same type (e.g. if you surround your script with double quotes and you want to insert a double quote), you need to escape these quotes by prepending them with a backslash - `\`.

For example you want to output `<a href="#url">Text</a>` and you have surrounded it in double quotes, you need to escape these double quotes in the HREF attribute by prepending them with a backslash `\`, so the result should be `<a href=\"#url\">Text</a>`.

The following are valid ways of escaping and displaying characters:

```
echo "it\" so nice to be here";
echo 'it\'s so nice to be here';
echo "it's so nice to be here"; // Different quotes, no need to escape
echo 'it"s so nice to be here'; // Different quotes, no need to escape
```

The following will result in an error:

```
echo 'it's so nice the be here';
```

Because the PHP interpreter will assume the expression to be ended with the quote found in `it's`, resulting in the rest of the line being treated is invalid code.

For more information you can read the PHP documentation on the [echo()](http://php.net/echo) function and this wonderful article on [Quotes and Strings](http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/phpTutorial/quotes.htm) as well.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to do this:

```
echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="?p='.($current_page + 1)'.">Next</a>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a template string with placeholders will make your code much more readable, easier to manage, and less likely to encounter buggy behaviors.

- `%d` is a placeholder for an integer.
- `%s` is a placeholder for a string.

Code:

```
$link = '&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="?p=%d">%s</a>';

printf($link, $current_page - 1, "Prev");
printf($link, $current_page + 1, "Next");
```